# How to model a plane to stretch over the letters for my logo?

Tags: animation

I have created a company logo and am in the process of making an animated intro of it.

[image]

I go to Mesh, click on Plane, move it to the beginning of the first letter, right-click the plane and add the first keyframe, stretch it out in edit mode, and add another keyframe, but there is no animation.

Comment: Manual alterations to a mesh are  not typically animatable.  ( You could Ctrl-H [Hook](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html#hook-modifier) one edge of your plane to an Empty, and animate the Empty's location, for example.. but there could well be simpler methods altogether.. if you present the problem itself, ( illustrated ?) then maybe folks will come up with another way.

Comment: you can animate mesh in edit mode with shape keys. maybe checkout this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OITWiN8Dplo

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Check the addons preference menu and enable the "AnimAll" addon.

Then you will find in the "N" properties panel its operators, where you can add keyframes  to vertices while in edit mode.

Be aware that you will have to be in object mode in order to preview the animation.

[image]